# How to add compiling argument in the C/C++ Compile Run Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've started using Linux, precisely Ubuntu 22.04.1, and while coding in C, i found myself with the need to use the getch() command, but when i was using Windows, i just had to include conio.h and everything was ok, the problem is that now in Ubuntu, the lib that does this is curses.h or ncurses.h

The quote is: I'm using VSCode, with the C/C++ Compile Run extension, and with it, pressing F6, which is the default shortcut to compile and run, it doesn't add -lcurses, nor -lncurses, and i recently discovered that it doesn't even add -lm, to math.h, thus making it necessary to compile and run via the vscode built-in terminaln using "gcc -o name name.c -lcurses" for example.

How do I modify this extension in VSCode to add the proper -lcurses, -lncurses and -lm libs in the compilation?

Comment: Not really responsive to the question, but don't use `conio.h`, which is a non-standard holdover from certain DOS-era C compilers, nor anything declared (only) in it.

Comment: I'm sure there are tons of tutorials how to setup a VSC project to link additional libraries. What does your web research reveal? And why does it not help you?